# JQuery tooltip visible only on input field focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, mouseover

How can I make the tooltip to be visible only on input field focus and hide the tooltip when the focus is gone. I don't want the tooltip to appear on `mouseover` or go invisible on `mouseout`.

Comment: any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 3):

```
$("input[id$=Textboxid]").focus(function() {
$("div[id$=tooltip]").show();
 });

 $("input[id$=Textboxid]").blur(function() {
 $("div[id$=tooltip]").hide();
});
```

this is general idea but you can manipulate according your needs

Comment: when even I add $(target).tooltip("open"); the hover event is set for the target, which makes the tooltip to appear on mouseover and disappear on mouseout, how can I fix that?

Comment: I have added the example here http://jsfiddle.net/P2Mws/  thanks for your time Garry

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue by unbinding the mouse events

```
$(target).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave mouseover mouseout');
```